# BCE0051: Operator '*' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'float' and a right hand side of type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

[image]

I did not learn javascript before, I totally don't know what I should do, cause I just follow other's project, hope someone can tell me how to modify these wrong places.Thank u T_T

Comment: You need to specify the type of your Object; you can only perform arithmetic on numeric types.  See http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/548699/how-am-i-getting-this-error.html

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
function aniSprite (columnSize,framepersecond,MoveDirection)
```

to

```
function aniSprite (columnSize,framepersecond:float,MoveDirection)
```

this error is happening because `Javascript` does not know that `framepersecond` is of type `float` and therefore it cannot multiply it with another `float`.

You have to explicitly tell it by using `framepersecond:float`